# 301 re-directs pointing from old asp CMS to new CMS php pages

Tags: redirect

I have an old cms site based on asp which I need to move to an PHP based CMS - I have searched for web.config examples (its running on a windows server). All the examples I find show re-directing html to html (which I can replicate on my server with a web.config file) when I try to re-direct something a bit more complicated the re-direct is ignored and the original page loads. Can someone give me an example of how I would re-direct from say:

http://www.domainname.co.uk/default.asp?contentID=2 to

http://www.samedomainname.co.uk/index.php?page=repair

I guess its just syntax knowledge - I have about half a dozen specific pages that I need to map to new pages and I do not want to lose the traffic !.

Cheers